# Blur Overlay expand on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, blur

I was wondering if someone can help me please, I am trying to expand a blur overlay on hover. I want the blur div to be centralised in the middle with a title and then on hover i would like the blur to expand out and overlay the background image. I have included an image of what I mean. [image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this using css3?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though a little jerky, this can work for you:

```css
.outerdivs
{
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: url('http://loremflickr.com/400/200');
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.outerdivs > h3
{
  color: rgb(255, 102, 2);
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.outerdivs .innerdivs
{
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('http://loremflickr.com/400/200');
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  height: 20%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}
.outerdivs .innerdivs img
{
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}

.outerdivs:hover .innerdivs
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdivs">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="innerdivs">
    <img src="http://loremflickr.com/400/200" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```